# Sort but do not compress numeric citations in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to have a citation style somewhat in between `numeric` and `numeric-comp`. To take the example from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), when `numeric` produces **[8, 3, 1, 7, 2]** and `numeric-comp` produces **[1–3, 7, 8]**, I would like to see **[1, 2, 3, 7, 8]**. As the only difference between the two styles seems to be `sortcites=true` and I can't find something like `compresscites`, I'm a bit lost even though this seems so trivial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `numeric-comp` style includes code for the compression, so you should load `numeric` and set `sortcites` yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sortcites]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{worman}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{loh}
\cite{kowalik,loh,almendro}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should have thought of testing this :/ Thank you for the MWE, too!