# Biblatex not compress specific group

Tags: biblatex, citing, sorting

I am doing a literature review. And I want to put references about a certain topic inside the table.

My question is very similar to: [Sort but do not compress numeric citations in BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61524/sort-but-do-not-compress-numeric-citations-in-biblatex)

However, I want only to disable the compression inside a table but keep sorting. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite:reinit}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}{}{\setcounter{cbx@tempcntb}{0}}}
\makeatother

\newtoggle{cite:comp}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iftoggle{cite:comp}{}{\usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}}
\toggletrue{cite:comp}
```

Inside the table environment you can disable compact citations with:

```
\togglefalse{cite:comp}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

I am wondering if it is possible to do the same using the package `cite.sty` only. There is a line `\let\@compress@cite\@empty` but I cannot put it working.

\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\citeu}[1]{
  \let\@compress@cite\@empty % disable compression
  \citenum{#1} % remove brackets around numbers
 }
 \let\cite\citeu
 \makeatother

Does not work :(

Comment: @cacamailg Ask a new question. The cite package bundle has nothing to do with biblatex.

Answer (score 4):

Numeric-comp seems to have some fairly complicated stuff in it, and it's not my usual hunting ground, but I think this will work.

What I've done is create a new cite command (`\citeu` for "cite uncompressed"): citations with `\cite` are compressed as normal; citations with `\citeu` are uncompressed, but still sorted. (In fact, the macros for them are just taken from the "ordinary" `numeric.cbx` style.)

For a cleaner interface you might like to set up an environment for your tables which would (within a group, of course) `let\cite\citeu`.

(The MWE is largely ... borrowed ... from the answer you have referenced).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\newbibmacro*{cite:uncomp}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeu}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:uncomp}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{worman}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{loh}
\cite{worman, kowalik,loh,almendro,knuth:ct:b}
\citeu{worman, kowalik,loh,almendro,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```